# run :!command in a real terminal

Tags: vim

I can use pudb (an ncurses Python debugger) in vim, because, for instance, `:!python %` runs in an actual terminal window. I prefer to use gvim, but gvim runs `:!python %` in the vim "dumb terminal."

Is there a way to change this behavior so gvim opens a separate terminal for commands? I think I recall having it work this way in the past.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can tell Vim to run a terminal, and run `python` in the terminal:

```
:!xterm -e 'python %; read'
```

`read` is there to let you see the output of your script before exiting the terminal.

Comment: That's it. Thank you very much.